# dplyr: If a column is present then evaluate an expression. If not return a `FALSE`

Tags: r, dplyr

I am getting myself confused with dplyr and `if_any`. I am trying to perform something along these lines:

> If a column is present then evaluate an expression. If not return a `FALSE`.

So these three scenarios capture what I am thinking:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(x = 1)

## GOOD: if foo_col is NA then return FALSE
dat %>%
  mutate(foo_col = NA_character_) %>%
  mutate(present = if_any(matches("foo_col"), ~ !is.na(.x)))
#>   x foo_col present
#> 1 1    <NA>   FALSE

## GOOD: if foo_col is not NA return FALSE
dat %>%
  mutate(foo_col = "value") %>%
  mutate(present = if_any(matches("foo_col"), ~ !is.na(.x)))
#>   x foo_col present
#> 1 1   value    TRUE

## NOT GOOD: if foo_col is absent, return TRUE? Want this to be FALSE.
dat %>%
  mutate(present = if_any(matches("foo_col"), ~ !is.na(.x)))
#>   x present
#> 1 1    TRUE
```

So can anyone suggest a way to determine how I could check for the `is.na` condition but also if the column is actually there?

Comment: Not sure how the `present = FALSE` will differ from the present = FALSE in the previous case when it is NA.  I would assume that it should return an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need the last to be `FALSE` while giving the TRUE/FALSE for the other two cases

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   mutate(present = ncol(pick(matches("foo_col"))) > 0 & 
                   if_any(matches("foo_col"), ~ !is.na(.x)))
```

-output

```
  x present
1 1   FALSE
```

---

Or as @boshek mentioned in the comments, `rlang::is_empty` should work as well

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(present = !rlang::is_empty((across(matches("foo_col")))) & 
                if_any(matches("foo_col"), ~ !is.na(.x)))
```

-output

```
  x present
1 1   FALSE
```

---

For the other cases

```
> dat %>%
+   mutate(foo_col = NA_character_) %>%
+   mutate(present = ncol(pick(matches("foo_col"))) > 0 &if_any(matches("foo_col"), ~ !is.na(.x)))
  x foo_col present
1 1    <NA>   FALSE
> dat %>%
+   mutate(foo_col = "value") %>%
+   mutate(present =  ncol(pick(matches("foo_col"))) > 0 & if_any(matches("foo_col"), ~ !is.na(.x)))
  x foo_col present
1 1   value    TRUE
```

NOTE: But this test cannot differentiate the `FALSE` from the `NA` cases and column not found `FALSE`

Comment: Where does `pick` come from?

Comment: @boshek I thought it is in the CRAN dplyr version.  But, I am using the devel version of dplyr.  Sorry

Comment: @boshek You could change the `pick` to `across` and it should work as well i.e. `dat %>%
    mutate(present = ncol(across(matches("foo_col"))) > 0 & 
                    if_any(matches("foo_col"), ~ !is.na(.x)))`

Comment: I love this. What about this slight modification to better communicate intent: `dat %>% mutate(present = !rlang::is_empty((across(matches("foo_col")))) & if_any(matches("foo_col"), ~ !is.na(.x)))`?

Comment: @boshek Thanks, I added that as an update in the post